# Find standard deviation of first differences of series defined with GROUP BY using RSQLite

Tags: sqlite, r, group-by

In SQLite I would like to find the standard deviation of the first differences of a (logged) series that I define with `GROUP BY`. My data provider gives me a daily price series, but I would like to find annualized daily volatility (the standard deviation of daily returns -- first difference of the natural log of the series -- over each year). I can bring the data to R, then use `ddply()`, but I would like to do this entirely in SQLite. I tried the `difference()` function from the [`RSQLite.extfunctions` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite.extfuns/RSQLite.extfuns.pdf), but my usage is wrong. I expected it to work like `diff()` in R, but I can't find much documentation.

This generates some data.

```
stocks <- 5
years <- 5
list.n <- as.list(rep(252, stocks * years))
list.mean <- as.list(rep(0, stocks * years))
list.sd <- as.list(abs(runif(stocks * years, min = 0, max = 0.1)))
list.po <- as.list(runif(n = stocks, min = 25, max = 100)) 
list.ret <- mapply(rnorm, n = list.n, mean = list.mean, sd = list.sd, SIMPLIFY = F)
my.price <- function(po, ret) po * exp(cumsum(ret))
list.price <- mapply(my.price, po = list.po, ret = list.ret, SIMPLIFY = F)
gvkey <- rep(seq(stocks), each = 252 * years)
day <- rep(seq(252), n = stocks * years)
fyr <- rep(seq(years), n = stocks, each = 252)
data.dly <- data.frame(gvkey, fyr, day, p = unlist(list.price))
```

Here is how I would do it with `ddply()` and the result.

```
# I could do this easily with ddply and subset
library(plyr)
data.dly <- ddply(data.dly, .(gvkey, fyr), transform, vol = sd(diff(log(p))))
data.ann <- subset(data.dly, day == 252)
head(data.ann)
     gvkey fyr day         p         vol
252      1   1 252  86.08568 0.077287182
504      1   2 252  43.32113 0.066741862
756      1   3 252  68.69734 0.084419564
1008     1   4 252  75.37267 0.006003969
1260     1   5 252  17.53583 0.083688727
1512     2   1 252 168.44656 0.035959492
```

And here is my (failed) SQLite attempt and error.

```
# but I can't figure it out in SQLite
library(RSQLite)
library(RSQLite.extfuns)
db <- dbConnect(SQLite())
init_extensions(db)
[1] TRUE
dbWriteTable(db, name = "data_dly", value = data.dly)
[1] TRUE
temp <- dbGetQuery(db, "SELECT stdev(difference(log(p))) FROM data_dly GROUP BY gvkey, fyr ORDER BY gvkey, fyr, day")
Error in sqliteExecStatement(con, statement, bind.data) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (error in statement: wrong number of arguments to function difference())
```

Does `difference()` need a comma separated list of numbers? Can I do this entirely in SQLite? Or do I need to perform in R? Thanks!

Comment: Minor style point: including the prompts in your code chunks makes it a pain to copy and paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this where `data.dly` is the data frame in the post:

```
library(sqldf)
out <- sqldf("select A.gvkey, A.fyr, stdev(log(A.p) - log(B.p)) vol
    from `data.dly` A join `data.dly` B 
    where A.day = B.day + 1 
        and A.gvkey = B.gvkey 
        and A.fyr = B.fyr 
    group by A.gvkey, A.fyr")
```

This gives:

```
> head(out)
  gvkey fyr        vol
1     1   1 0.09312510
2     1   2 0.01905447
3     1   3 0.01651095
4     1   4 0.06962667
5     1   5 0.05243940
6     2   1 0.03039751
```

Answer (score 2):

The [difference SQL command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188753.aspx) takes two character arguments, and has a different meaning to R's `diff` command.

Retrieve the data with an SQL command, then do stats using R.

```
temp <- dbGetQuery(db, "SELECT p FROM data_dly GROUP BY gvkey, fyr ORDER BY gvkey, fyr, day")
sd(diff(log(temp$p)))
```

Comment: Thanks. AFAIK, there's no way to call an R function within SQLite. Is that correct?

Comment: @richardh - I think the only way to do that would be to write a C function that in turn calls R, as mentioned [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/sqlite-and-r-td2014508.html). Also, you might consider sending a note to the RSQLite.extfuns maintainer that perhaps `difference` shouldn't be listed among the math functions to avoid further confusion...